# apk size bloats when switched from admob standalone SDK to google play services SDK

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

With Admob SDK my apk size is 230Kb.
When replaced Admob SDK with google play services SDK it is 1.5MB(More than 6 times bloat).

I guess full 'google play services client SDK' becomes part of my app and hence the bloat.

How to only include 'Ads' component alone from 'google play services client SDK'?

Thanks

Comment: "How to only include 'Ads' component alone from 'google play services client SDK'?" -- AFAIK, you can't. The problem probably comes from resources, as I know that the Play Service library project has lots of strings in lots of translations. There is work being done to find ways to optimize this as part of the new Gradle-based build system.

Comment: 6 years later nowadays google play ads increases my app by 2.7MB, but there is a 'lite' version if you are looking to shrink it

Answer (score 3):

I didn't wanted to change the standalone Admob SDK for the Google Play Services for the same reason. My apk almost tripled it size with the new library. But with Admob deprecating the old SDK, it's time to start using it.

As CommosnWare mentioned, the number of resources that comes with the library is a problem. I decompiled my apk, and found out that there were a lot of images for G+ related things. As in this particular app I only use the Admob capabilities, I decided to override those images, and doing that **the apk reduced its size 292Kb**.

To override those resources, I created empty images and put them on my app's drawable folders with the same exact names. Android studio use those resources instead of the library ones.

[image: Overrided resources]

If you want you can download the resources I used from here: http://goo.gl/loIf2l

I haven't use this on production yet, and I don't know if this could be against Google Play Services TOS. But it's the only way I've found to reduce the size of the app after adding Google Play Services. I hope they provide a better solution soon.

Comment: This might violate google's TOS . check #9 here .  http://bigknol.com/admob-account-disabled-after-implementation/

Comment: Any update on this implementation??. did u try to use this in production?? I am publishing a new app soon and really want to know if this method worked out for you!

Comment: Hi Akshit, I've used this on an app with no problem so far. So it has worked for me, but this is just a particular case. And although I think this is not against TOS, I'm not sure about it. I still hope they provide a better solution. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem like you. I imported its jar file instead of libproject and used proguard to filter only classes from com.google.android.gms.ads.** and it turned out fine. The apk file was 100KB more than using standalone Admob SDK. But I don't know if it worked on any cases.

Answer (score 0):

The ads client is now compartmentalized into  `play-services-ads`. Even better, you can now use dependency `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite`, which is a smaller library. It added 'only' about 4k method references to my optimized APK. https://admob.googleblog.com/2016/07/keep-your-android-apps-nimble-with.html